# C++ accessing values of a struct with pointer+1

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

So I am trying to access the value of a struct using "pointer+1" but it gives me this error "[main] listTest 8320 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace t
o listTest.exe.stackdump". If I use just a pointer without the "+1" to acces the value it works. When I print out both pointers I get addresses but like I said I can not acces the value of the (pointer+1).

Here is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct item
{
    string value;
    struct item *next;
    struct item *before;
};

int main()
{
    item *beg, *end, *temp, *tempBefore, *tempNext;

    temp = new (item);
    temp->value = "Hello";
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->before = NULL;
    beg = temp;
    end = temp;

    // add to the end of list
    temp = new (item);
    temp->value = "World";
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->before = end;
    end->next = temp;
    end = temp;

    // add to the beginning of list
    temp = new(item);
    temp->value = "Reiska";
    temp->next = beg;
    temp->before = NULL;
    beg->before = temp;
    beg = temp;

    // add to the middle of list (between first and second)
    tempBefore = beg;
    tempNext = beg + 1;
    cout << tempNext << " " << tempBefore << endl; // prints both addresses
    cout << tempNext->value << " " << tempBefore->value << endl; // the error i mentioned earlier
    temp = new(item);
    temp->value = "Kiulu";
    temp->before = tempBefore;
    temp->next = tempNext;
    tempBefore->next = temp;
    tempNext->before = temp;
```

Thanks for all the -reps. I definetly got the concept of a linked list wrong but is that why u -rep? Or is my explanation unlcear?

Comment: The next item is in `next`, not immediately next to it in memory.

Comment: Why do you think that should do anything useful? You have no array!

Comment: This may be C in the sense that you use 'new' for dynamic allocation. However, you should invest some time to learn about encapsulation, RAII and interfaces. 'item' is crying out to have a constructor and a destructor (unless you are obliged to interface with C code).

Comment: Sometimes people down-vote on questions which they think are too basic and can be answered with enough reading of documentation. I think it's pretty clear what you're asking, but it could be made more explicit by phrasing it as a question. e.g. "Why do I get the following error?" rather than "I'm getting the following error".

Comment: If you value your readers time, you can remove everything not directly relevant, thereby creating a minimal test case https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. As it stands I would i) not down vote your question if you show interest in how to improve asking question ii) down vote if I get the impression that you don't care much about your readers time.

Comment: If you can reframe your specific questions, which is probably only relevant to you, into a generic (but specific) question interesting to a broader audience you have also increased your chance of getting up votes instead of down votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be mixing up the concept of a linked list with the concept of an array. In a traditional linked list, each element is allocated separately on the heap, and there is no reason for the allocations to be contiguous in memory. That is why you have a `next` pointer to tell you where the next element is.

When you use the expression `beg + 1`, you are accessing the memory location that is one `struct item` worth of memory after `beg`, which is not necessarily valid memory. In your case, you get an error because you probably don't have permission to read that memory.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I definetly thought about it wrong. So instead of tempNext = beg + 1; i did tempNext = beg->next; and it works. If i want to put an item to the 3rd place for example, is my only option to use a loop and i start from beginning and go forward one by one until im at the spot i want to be and then add the item there because the items arent next to each other in memory? Did i get it right?

Comment: @iWillBeMaster, Yes, that is correct. You can only traverse a linked list one element at a time since they are not contiguous in memory.

Comment: @iWillBeMaster that's why we can say that array are "random access" and linked list are not: you access directly any value inside the array, with the linked list you have to traverse the previous value to access the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do (pointer+1) here because the location next to `beg` pointer is not necessarily in your list. Memory is not allocated in a continuous order, unless you have used an array or something similar.

What you can do instead is

```
tempNext=beg->next;
```